# How can I debug specific functions?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a website that has several different functions . I can get to my website by using localhost:5000/ , when I run it in debug mode using vscode-go debugger I get the following message 
 **API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:52238**

I have a Name function that returns several strings but I can not hit the breakpoint in debug mode . I put a breakpoint in my Name function and put the url as follows:   *127.0.0.1:52238/name* however it does not hit the breakpoint. What could be going on here ? My code is below if i run the application normally and put http://localhost:5000/name then everything works but in debug mode this **127.0.0.1:52238/name** does not hit the breakpoint or page . I am using Go as a backend api so I'll need to hit url endpoints to see what's going on. **Is there someway that I can make the debug port also :5000** ?

```
  -- Main 
 package main

 import (
     "github.com/gorilla/mux"
     "runtime"
     "./Models"
     "./Controllers"
 )

 func main() {

  Controllers.CircleRoutes(r)

     srv := &http.Server{
         ReadTimeout:  20 * time.Second,
         WriteTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
         IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second,
         Addr:         ":5000",
     }

     srv.ListenAndServe()
    }



   // Circles Route

 package Controllers

func Name(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var result string
    r.ParseForm()
    result = "Success"

    io.WriteString(w, result)
}

 func CircleRoutes(r *mux.Router) {
     r.HandleFunc("/name", Name)
 }
```

Comment: What debugger are you using? how ? you are not giving enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are using vscode-go debugger.
You can configure the port from launch.json configuration file from your vscode.

The config should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "GOPATH": <your GOPATH>
            },
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ],
    "go.lintTool": "gometalinter"
}
```

You can change port from above settings. To find `launch.json`, just `ctrl+P` and type launch.json it will show dropdown result of search in your vscode.